# How do I make first names abbreviated and be listed as surname, first name in natbib?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I use the `natbib` citation management package and the `unsrtnat` bibliography style in my thesis. I have superscript numbering in the citation call-outs.

In the bibliography, the full first names are listed, and full names are listed as `FullFirstname Surname`. How can I change this to `Surname, FirstNameInitial.`?

e.g. One reference is David B. Burr etc., but I want this listed as Burr, D.B.

This is in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[square,super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you wish to display abbreviated first names *without space* between initials; e.g., `D.B.`, not `D. B.`.

If this assumption is correct, I suggest your proceed as follows:

- Find the file `unsrtnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `unsrtnat-initials.bst`. (Do *not* edit an unmodified & unrenamed file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `unsrtnat-initials.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the file `unsrtnat-initials.bst`, find the function called `format.names`. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 216.
- In the `format.names` function, locate the following line:

  ```
      { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
      { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, f{.}.}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  I trust you can sort-of figure out what this change achieves: Instead of composing a full name as `{fullfirstname[s]}{von component}{lastname}{, junior component}`, BibTeX now composes it as `{von component}{lastname}{, abbreviatedfirstname[s] without space between abbreviated initials}{, junior component}`.

  Of course, if you prefer to place the "junior component" [if present] immediately after the surname rather than at the very end, you should use

  ```
     { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f{.}.}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  For instance, this setup would display the name of [Robert Emerson Lucas, Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Lucas_Jr.) as `Lucas, Jr., R.E.` rather than `Lucas, R.E., Jr.`. Just choose whatever typesetting convention you're comfortable with. (By the way, you'd have to enter this person's name as `author={Lucas, Jr., Robert Emerson}` in the bib file -- note the two commas.)
- Save the file `unsrtnat-initials.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution. If you have no idea what the preceding sentence means, I recommend you select the first option.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-initials}` and perform a full recompile cycle -- latex, bibtex, and latex twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{x, author={David B. Burr}, title={Thoughts}, year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[square,super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-initials}

\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, there was no chance I was going to figure that out by myself. Much appreciated.

Comment: @SammieDavies - You're most welcome!