Bibliography with authors last name followed by initials using natbib package
In my current document, each bibliography item appears such that the author's first and last names are presented. However, as per the journal formatting, I wish to present each bibliography item such that the author's last name is given first followed by the initials.
This is my MWE
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,hidelinks]{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage{bibunits}
% \setcitestyle{citesep={;}, aysep={,}}
% \renewcommand\harvardyearleft{\unskip, }
% \renewcommand\harvardyearright[1]{.}

\begin{document}


\title{This is my title}

\author{}
\date{}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle {empty}

\newpage

% \newpage

\section{Introduction}

This is the citation \citet{chandra2016productivity} and this is by \citet{aragon2017hospital}

\renewcommand*{\refname}{\vspace*{-2em}}
\vspace*{2em} 
\section*{References} \hypertarget{exercises}{}
\bookmark[level=section,dest=exercises]{References} 
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % can change to agsm but ask the questions on tex and how to remove the brackets using apa style
\bibliography{3rdbib} 


\end{document}

The two references appear as:

But I want to have the author's last name first followed by the initials. So ideally the first reference looks like this:

Any suggestions on how to do this? Please note that the journal requires references to be numbered.
Thank you.

(1) Please make your example as minimal as possible, clearly most of those packages have nothing to do with citations. (2) why is this tagged with biblatex when it is not used. (3)  bibtex styles are not really customizable. Either you then make a style manually (very difficult) or perhaps actually switch to biblatex (it can emulate the interface from natbib)

I have made the MWE more simple and also removed the biblatex tag from the question.

You can remove chapterbib as well.

Yes I have removed this too.

I have found the solution from this link:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542613/how-do-i-make-first-names-abbreviated-and-be-listed-as-surname-first-name-in-na I simply had to slightly modify the unsrtnat.bst file.
